Concurrent http requests in .NET
I am trying to make many concurrent http requests to external API. The code which i wrote is definitely faster than the normal synchronous version (6x faster), but its still too slow. The avarage time of the one normal request to this endpoint is about 2.5 sec. I don't know why in this case all requests are not processed immediately but with some delay.
The code which i wrote:
var tasks = new List<Task<APIResponse>>();
            
for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
{
     tasks.Add(_downloader.GetAsync(i, cancellationToken));
}
            
var awaitedTasks = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

public async Task<APIResponse> GetAsync(int pageNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _httpClientFactory.CreateClient()
                .GetAsync($"{Url}{pageNumber}", cancellationToken);

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<APIResponse>(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("API Error.");
        throw;
    }
}

There is the fragment of logs:
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 2743.0713ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 2759.5243ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 2719.747ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 2729.4193ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 2977.4628ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 2990.8073ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 3270.9693ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 3284.1818ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 4296.9246ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 4309.4065ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 4692.3584ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 4712.5791ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 4678.2024ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 4692.6874ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 5139.1964ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 5156.143ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 5814.296ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 5827.4973ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 6290.0982ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 6307.252ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 6962.2691ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 6981.6972ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 6885.6879ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 6898.9493ms - 200


Probably partially to do with the thread limits see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getminthreads?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Threading_ThreadPool_GetMinThreads_System_Int32__System_Int32__ and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/specifying-threads-per-processor-on-iis (assuming the external API is hosted by IIS)
